# Automatically initialising multiple Vue.js3 Single File Components each within its own Vue instance

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

I'd like to have multiple Vue3 components. Each as a separate Vue instance, and all automatically loaded.

Why? Because I want to use them on a page where there's potentially many other JS scripts that alter the page so I cannot change the DOM for them (by globally initialising Vue) and I want not to worry that they will mess with my Vue components - so mounting all my components to some one big Vue instance like `<body id="app">` is not an option.

With Vue2 it was a bit easier but does not work with Vue3. Now after some fight I worked out a solution for Vue3 it works fine but it seems ugly in my eyes so I assume there's a better one :)

I'm using ([laravel-mix](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/vue) - [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) solution for building my files).

Here's my HTML file with the components embedded:

```
// index.php

<TestOne data-vue-component="TestOne" />
<TestTwo data-vue-component="TestTwo" />
<TestOne data-vue-component="TestOne" />
```

And here's my JS file for loading those components:

```
// index.js

import { createApp } from 'vue';

const vueComponents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-vue-component]');
if (vueComponents.length) {
    vueComponents.forEach((elem) => {

       const componentName = elem.getAttribute('data-vue-component');
       const app = createApp(require(`./components/${componentName}/${componentName}.vue`).default);
       app.mount(elem);
    }
}
```

So I look for the Vue components using data attribute `data-vue-component` and then for each one found I get the component's name, create a Vue3 instance importing the component at the same moment. Finally I mount it and do the same with the next one.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I really don't understand this statement, *"Because I want to use them on a page where there's potentially many other JS scripts that alter the page so I cannot change the DOM for them (by globally initialising Vue) and I want not to worry that they will mess with my Vue components - so mounting all my components to some one big Vue instance like <body id="app"> is not an option."* If you don't get a decent answer soon, please consider clarifying this a bit.

Comment: Maybe try teleports? https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html#basic-usage

Comment: @Ifaruki - probably a solution if I put all components in some confined area of the page and then teleport their outputs to required locations, but that would complicate things even more.

Comment: It's unknown what is the relation of these elements to the rest of the page. An app shouldn't be necessarily `body`, it could be any container. Otherwise,

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels if I use the whole area of the page as I need to and mount my one and only instance to `<body>` then (since there is possibility for third party scripts Vue/JS inside of the body) I could end up with overlapping Vue instances, problems with my Vue instance removing (during mount) attached to DOM events (or the other way around), at least that was the case with Vue2.